# join based on condition, remove a part of substring from column value

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, join, substr

I would like to join 2 column of 2 tables by replacing a pattern in the start of column.

table1:

ABC_somename_ABC

something_XYZ

Table2:

somename_ABC

somthing_XYZ

Here i have to replace the ABC_ part at the starting not at the end and make an equi join. In second case it should not replace as it doesnot have ABC_

I tried using substr,instr functions to remove  till first underscore.
SUBSTR (column, INSTR (column, '*') + 1) this would start with any underscore but i want that to work only when it starts with ABC* or XYZ_

Used regular expression REGEXP_SUBSTR ('ABC_somename_ABC','[^*]+', 1,2) is replacing both sides.
i have only 2 patterns in the starting which have to removed like ABC*, XYZ_
could someone help me on this.

Comment: One way to get a clear answer would be to provide a [SQLfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4) with your structure and a desired output.

Comment: thanks for site dint know abt it til date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you just want to join on the end of the string:

```
on t1.col like '%' || t2.col
```

If you really want to test for "ABC_" at the beginning:

```
on (t1.col like 'ABC\_%' and t1.col like '%' || t2.col) or
   (t1.col not like 'ABC\_% and t1.col = t2.col)
```

Note: underscore (`'_'`) is a wildcard for the `like` expression, so it should be escaped.